# Angular 6 - View of child component do not updating

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

i have two components , in the first one i have an  **array input**

the first component is :

```
@Input('data')
    set ungroupedData(ungroupedData: any[]) {
        this._ungroupedData = null;
        this.groupedData = [];
        this._ungroupedData = ungroupedData;
        this.columnManager = [];
        this.cdr.detectChanges();

        if (ungroupedData) {
            this.jsonKeys = Object.keys(this.ungroupedData[0]);
            let groupBy: string = this.jsonKeys[0] ? this.jsonKeys[0] : "";

            if (this.groupingColumn && this.groupingColumn.length > 0) {
                groupBy = this.groupingColumn;
            }

            this.groupedData = this.groupStructural(groupBy, this.ungroupedData);
            this.groupKeys = Object.keys(this.groupedData);

            // Fill columnContainer
            for (var groupKey of this.groupKeys) {
                var x: ColumnContainer = new ColumnContainer();

                x.add([{
                    jsonKey: this.displayColumn,
                    name: groupKey,
                    width: 90,
                    type: EColumnType.text,
                    clickable: EColumnClickable.clickable,
                    routerURL: '/bulletin-officiel/access-chronologique/detail/',
                    routerKey: 'tid',
                    sortable: false,
                    order: 0
                },
                {
                    jsonKey: "pdf",
                    name: "PDF",
                    width: 10,
                    type: EColumnType.icon,
                    clickable: EColumnClickable.clickable,
                    imageURL: "/assets/projets/images/pdf.png",
                    sortable: false,
                    order: 1
                }]);

                this.columnManager.push(x);
            }
        } else {
            this._ungroupedData = null;
        }
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }

    @Input('groupBy') groupingColumn: string;
    @Input('display') displayColumn: string;

    private _groupedData: any;
    public get groupedData() {
        return this._groupedData
    };
    public set groupedData(newData: any) {
        this._groupedData = [];
        this.cdr.detectChanges();   
        this._groupedData = newData;
    }
    public jsonKeys: string[];
    public groupKeys: string[];

    private columnManager: ColumnContainer[];

    constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
        this.columnManager = [];
    }
```

In the view of the second component i call the first one and passe the data to it like so .

```html
<app-dynamic-tree [data]="data" groupBy="label" display="ttitreLFr"></app-dynamic-tree>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 50%; right: 50%">
    <ngx-spinner bdColor="trasparent"
                 size="medium"
                 color="#2288bd"
                 type="ball-clip-rotate"></ngx-spinner>
</div>
```

The Api was called, but the view of the first component do not update.I don't know what exactly the source of the  problem .
i wonder if there is some solution?
thanks a lot.

Comment: add html template of the first component and typescript of the second component, or ideally create http://stackblitz.com demo.

Comment: Thanks  you ,  @Ludevik here is the link of the code you ask .

   [code of first component](https://angular-ynbtrv.stackblitz.io)

Comment: creating stackblitz demo doesn't mean to just copy the code there. Create working demo that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: you are right @Ludevik , but the demo do not work because the component in witch i have problems need more ones to work  as good demo.

Comment: [code of two components ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6ccrvm?file=src%2Fbulletin-officiel-summary%2Fbulletin-officiel-summary.component.html)

Comment: It still doesn't work. It is hard to find the problem. Could you make it work and could you remove all unnecessary stuff from there?

Comment: yeah @Ludevik i know, it is hard to find the problem like so, but  it's not possible to have demo that's work  thanks you for help .